# Texmaker can't find my bibtex file

Tags: bibtex, errors, texmaker

I'm working with TexMaker

I made a bibliography.bib file and I've put in in the same folder as my .tex files (I've tried making a .bib file by hand and with BibDesk, but neither work).

In my project.tex file I put

```
\documentclass[]{article} 
\begin{document}
some text \cite{evocomp}
some more text
\bibliography{bibliography} 
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\end{document}
```

And my bib file looks like this (I've only made one reference so far...):

```
@article{evocomp,
Author = {name},
Date-Added = {2014-04-06 17:32:05 +0000},
Date-Modified = {2014-04-06 17:34:26 +0000},
Journal = {Methods},
Pages = {39-55},
Title = {some title},
Volume = {62},
Year = {2013}}
```

then I compile once as Latex and then as Bibtex and this is where is goes wrong.

I get the following message:

> bibtex: Need exactly one file argument. Try `bibtex --help' for more information.

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

For your information I'm working with OS X Mavericks (so also just tell me if latex just doesn't work at all with this...)

**UPDATE** my problem is solved now, there was something wrong with the bibtex command in my preferences so texmaker couldn't find my .bib file.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you have `\cite` commands in your document? And how are you running `bibtex`? Turning this into a complete minimal (non-)working example would be helpful.

Comment: I changed my example a bit, so I hope it's better now, as you can see I did add a \cite command. I don't really know what you mean by how am I running bibtex, I've installed the MacTex 2013 package if that's what you mean, but if I need to install something else as well, that could maybe be my problem?

Comment: You need to say on the commandline: `bibtex <filename>` or `bibtex <filename>.aux`, where <filename> is the name of your `.tex` file.  So: given a `myfile.tex`.  I do: `latex myfile`, `bibtex myfile`, `latex myfile`, `latex myfile`.  (The extensions are implicitly understood to be `myfile.tex`, `myfile.aux`, `myfile.tex`, `myfile.tex`.)

Comment: In the Texmaker settings, what does the BibTeX command look like?

Comment: @jon wel thats what I do and when I do the `bibtex myfile` command I get an error.

@TorbjørnT. `"/usr/texbin/bibtex" % .aux` , this is what it looks like (if that's what you mean?)

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Is there a space between `%` and `.aux`? If so, remove it.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thank you! that was indeed the problem, I have no idea how that space got there, but it's gone now and everything works perfectly.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a configuration error that the OP was able to solve on his/her own.

Answer (score 1):

In Texmaker's settings, the BibTeX command reads

```
"/usr/texbin/bibtex" % .aux
```

but it should be

```
"/usr/texbin/bibtex" %.aux
```

without the space between `%` and `.aux`.